# Do differential analog output signals "mirror" one another?

Tags: analog, differential

Let's say I have a sensor that produces a differential analog output signal. Each signal line is floating relative to ground. Is it *typical* for that differential signal to be "mirrored" such that each output line varies? Or would it be more common for one of the output lines to be held constant and have just one of the differential lines actually be updated?

Referring to the [image below from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signalling), the source produces two signals that contribute to half the output pulse. Thus in this diagram, each differential output is varied.

However, one of the lines could have just been held to some constant.

[image]

Comment: It would depend on the sensor.  It doesn't make sense to generalize.

Comment: Make your mind up. Are you talking analogue signals that are differential (and impedance balanced) or, are you wanting to consider a digital signal that is differential (and also must be impedance balanced for maximum signal security). Make your mind.

Comment: You mentioned about differential outputs, then show a single ended output configuration. Most fully differential input/output amplifiers have output signals that are balanced and inverted with respect to one another. Otherwise it would be a costly waste to use that architecture (power, area, etc).

Comment: Not necessarily, There can be a "common mode" signal which (a) is not mirrored and (b) is removed by the subtractor. This is why diff signalling is used : common mode signals are often interference.